# Why am I getting the following error "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory"?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-compute-engine

I am running a headless selenium script from a VM instance on Google Cloud. The script was working fine (when run manually), however, since creating a cronjob which runs every hour I've been getting an

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory.
```

Any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Does it run any number of times with the cron before you get this error?

Is your selenium driver completely closing when it is done? I have had times in the past where I have had to go into task manager to close these drivers out.

Make sure you you have a proper teardown at the end of your script.